# Is it legal to develop iOS apps on Windows?

Tags: ios, development

Is it legal to develop for iOS on a Windows machine? I have researched this on Google, but I do not seem to be able to find a direct answer, yes or no, whether it is legal or illegal to do iOS app development on Windows.

Here is an article that I have found regarding the legal issue (or lack of): http://www.pmbaty.com/iosbuildenv/legal.html

Is it legal to develop iOS apps on a non-Apple hardware such as a Dell or Lenovo machine or any other hardware which is generally made for Windows or Linux? or On vmware?

With regard to location, I am talking about India, or otherwise non-US resident.

Comment: If you could show what search terms you used or what reference you think makes this against any rules, that would strengthen the question...  Also, legal depends on location, better to clarify whose terms or license you are afraid of breaking since they can be commented on more generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

…it's legal to develop iOS apps on hardware or software other than Macs and OS X respectively as it does not violate the Registered Apple Developer Agreement:

- https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/registered_apple_developer_20100301.pdf

You can develop iOS apps on any platform that you can, using a variety of software available. The legal problems come from running OS X on unsupported hardware, or running pre-release software without being a developer, etc.

Comment: Legal where? Legal how?  Better to be more precise about what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as long as you pay your developer fees if you wanna launch apps on appstore. But running OSX other than on an Apple device is illegal as the software is only sold on Macs and not for the public and its made not to work on any other platform.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not, at least not with the "PMBaty iOS Buildenv",
it's a pure license violation.

The iOS SDK can only be legally used on Apple Systems.

http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf:

> You agree not to install, use or run the SDK on any non-Applebranded computer, or to enable others to do so.

I have asked that guy to provide the source code for the GPL programs
that he is using (cctools, ldid, etc.), but he has strictly ignored my e-mails regarding to that.

He has also violated the Cygwin license in the past.

That guy is a shame.